# Instanciar imagenes en método que crea un PDF

Tags: java, imagen, clase

necesito instanciar unas imagenes en un método que me crea un pdf, las tengo guardadas en el mismo paquete que la clase donde las necesito usar.
Cuando ejecuto desde el IDE no hay problema con ellas pero cuando hago el .jar no me las muestra. He mirado como hacerlo pero no me funciona bien, includo haciendo carpeta en el proyecto y pasandole la ruta y no hay manera.
¿Alguien que me pueda dar una pista?

Gracias

Comment: Edita tu pregunta añadiendo lo que has intentado, osea codigo.

Comment: Bueno ya está solucionado, la instrucción que me ha servido es esta:         Image img= Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("/imagen/miImagen.jpg"));

Answer (score 0):

Bueno ya está solucionado, la instrucción que me ha servido es esta:
**Image img= Image.getInstance(getClass().getResource("/imagen/miImagen.jpg"));**